# Duplicate data from a recursive CTE query using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, duplicates, common-table-expression

I have the following CTE query to look up if a technician was already sent to fix a problem to the client home.

This table contains relational data between installations. It tells me if install A is linked with B, then if B is linked with D, thus making A and D linked. This can go on for 90 different entries to create one large relational scheme.

INIR_Id : ID

INIR_INST_Id : Installations ID

INIR_INRE_Id Relation ID

INIR_Date : Date that the relation was added.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CPL_t_Installations_InstallationsRelations](
    [INIR_Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [INIR_INST_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [INIR_INRE_Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [INIR_Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CPL_t_Installations_InstallationsRelations] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [INIR_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


WITH Tempou(Relation,Installation,Date,Origine)AS
(
    (
        SELECT
            INIR_INRE_Id,
            INIR_INST_Id,
            INIR_Date,
            1
        FROM
            CPL_t_Installations_InstallationsRelations
        WHERE
            (INIR_INST_Id=@INST_Id)
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT
            INIR_INRE_Id,
            INIR_INST_Id,
            INIR_Date,
            0
        FROM
            CPL_t_Installations_InstallationsRelations
                INNER JOIN Tempou Alpha ON(Relation=INIR_INRE_Id)
        WHERE
            (INIR_Date<Date)
            AND NOT
            (
                (Installation=INIR_INST_Id)
                AND
                (Relation=INIR_INRE_Id)
            )
    )
)
SELECT TOP * FROM Tempou;
```

The problem with the query is that it loops back to every date present in the CTE result set. Every results then get duplicated a number of time. I have made it from an infinite number of time to a result set of 128 entries using the date as a monitoring data. But if we use a DISTINCT to query everything from Tempou, we are down do 14 results, which is the correct number. There is no hierarchical data except, at best, the date data.

I've been working on this for a few days, from unlimited results to 128 is pretty good, but it's not the answer. I might be quite tired and can't see the obvious to this problem. Leaving me to ask you all what I can't see.

Ps.: I have no data to share as example, but there is no limit to the number of "level" of results, some clients might have 2 levels, some might have 20. And the linked data is of course not symmetric, some "roots" might be shorter than others.

Thank you!

Small addition, if I could user "Tempou" to do a "NOT EXISTS" the problem would be solved, but it's not possible with a CTE which duplicate every entries. So I am really trying to find a way to changed the CTE in a way to be able to replicate that behaviour.

Comment: Adding aliases to your joins and using them on all references might give us a better idea of what you are trying to do.  Showing us the table schemas would also help.

Comment: At least one problem "INNER JOIN CPL_t_Installations_InstallationsRelations ON(INIR_INRE_Id=INRE_Id)"  INIR_INRE_Id of which table, INRE_Id of which table ....

Comment: @bummi
I updated the query to correct it. That snippet of code should now have been there, I most likely uploaded a version that I was toying with.

Answer (score 0):

@Rv3, first off, `SELECT TOP * FROM Tempou` wouldn't compile but I will leave it as a typo

Quick question, is your CTE going into infinite loop? try switching them in the JOIN and see if it works.
Instead of

```
FROM
            CPL_t_Installations_InstallationsRelations
                INNER JOIN Tempou Alpha ON(Relation=INIR_INRE_Id)
        WHERE
            (INIR_Date < Date)
            AND NOT
            (
                (Installation=INIR_INST_Id)
                AND
                (Relation=INIR_INRE_Id)
            )
```

Try

```
FROM
            Tempou Alpha 
                INNER JOIN  (Select * from  CPL_t_Installations_InstallationsRelations 
                            WHERE
            (INIR_Date < Date)
            AND NOT 
            (
                (Installation=INIR_INST_Id)
                AND
                (Relation=INIR_INRE_Id)
            )
            ) temp_tab
            ON(Relation=temp_tab.INIR_INRE_Id)
```

Obviously I haven't tried running this so apologies if you will need to fix a little bit to get it working.